# how to read hiera value in custom factor

Tags: puppet, puppet-enterprise, facter, librarian-puppet

I would like to read value from the hiera for my custom factor. Is it possible ?

I am going to populate a factor based on my hiera value. Please look at my following code for your reference.

```
require 'facter'

# Default for non-Linux nodes
Facter.add(:jboss_base_algorithm) do
    setcode do
        nil
    end
end

# Linux
#
Facter.add(:jboss_base_algorithm) do
    confine :kernel  => :linux
    setcode do
        Facter::Util::Resolution.exec("/usr/bin/echo '{hiera_value}' | /usr/bin/base64")
    end
end
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Custom facts cannot rely on Hiera in a master / agent configuration, because facts are evaluated by the agent whereas the Hiera data live on the master.

Custom facts probably *shouldn't* rely on Hiera data even for local manifest application, in part because that inhibits switching to master / agent, and in part because **the data are already accessible directly from Hiera**.  You don't need a custom fact to access the data.